portfolio rebalance weight up and down
I am rebalancing portfolio , where my algorithm has recommended new securities also there are  few existing in my portfolio. For simplicity , let's say I want to wight my securities  based in mean return. New securities  are included because they have high returns.
Screenshot for example is given

There could be cases where in spreadsheet I have only existing securities and all have negative returns. That mean no new security is recommended. as shown below

aim is in invest/weight up  in securities that are expected to give positive returns and weight down the securities that are expected to give negative returns.
what could be  single right approach (formula) to handle different cases .

Your question is not specific enough. There are way too many answers. For example, you could try a simple equal-weighted approach based on assets that have a positive mean return as of today, you could take the top 10% of assets as of today, you could long and short top and bottom 10% etc.
